# Замыкания в JS. Как создать массив ID для печати

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Задача следующая:
Есть кнопка для добавления ID объекта в печать, ID подставляется динамически.

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onclick="addPrint(48)">
  <i class="material-icons left">print</i>
  В печать
</a>
```

При нажатии на кнопку, ID передается в функцию:

```
function addPrint(id){
   var idToPrint = [];
   return function pushId(){
     return idToPrint.push(id);
   };
}
```

Я пытаюсь сделать так, что бы все эти ID сохранялись в массив idToPrint = [], что бы в дальнейшем с ними работать, вывести на печать через другую функцию. Как я понял, реализовать это правильно без глобальных переменных, через замыкания. 

Что не получается: проверить, сохраняются ли значения в idToPrint или нет и как правильно потом "вытянуть" этот массив оттуда?

  Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лексическое окружение функции уничтожается после её выполнения.
Поэтому `idToPrint` хоть и выносится замыканием, но не используется, что ведёт к её уничтожению.
Вот пример реализации:

```js
let log = document.querySelector('#log'), toPrint = [];

const addPrint = n => (log.innerHTML += `Добавлено ${n}` + '<br />') && toPrint.push(n);
const print    = _ => log.innerHTML += (toPrint.length ? `Печатаем: ${toPrint.join`, `}` : `Печатать нечего`) + '<br />';
```

```css
a{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onclick="addPrint(16)">
  <i class="material-icons left">print16</i>
  В печать
</a><br />
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onclick="addPrint(35)">
  <i class="material-icons left">print35</i>
  В печать
</a><br />
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onclick="addPrint(42)">
  <i class="material-icons left">print42</i>
  В печать
</a><br />
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onclick="addPrint(856)">
  <i class="material-icons left">print856</i>
  В печать
</a><hr />
<input type='button' onclick='print();' value='Печатать!' /><br /><br />
<div id='log'></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, он мне помог.

Comment: @Igor, всегда рад помочь.

Answer (score 1):

```
var idController = {
  idToPrint: [],
  pushId: function(id){
    return this.idToPrint.push(id);
  },
  getIds: function(){
    return this.idToPrint.slice(); // .slice() копия масива
  },
};
idController.pushId(....);
... = idController.getIds();
```

Но это оверинжиниринг, лучше сделай глобальную, если проект небольшой.

Answer (score 0):

Полный швах! Смотрите, что у Вас происходит. У Вас есть глобальный объект - функция `addPrint`. При **каждом** вызове этой функции создается новый локальный массив `idToPrint` и локальный объект-замыкание при вызове которого (а оно нигде не вызывается) id добавится в свою копию `idToPrint`. К слову, если я не ошибаюсь то конструкция

> `return function pushId(){`

Вообще должна приводить к ошибке компиляции. Должно быть так

```
return function (){
  ....
}
```

если вы хотите возвратить объект-замыкание или так

```
return (function (){
  ....
})()
```

если вы  хотите возвратить результат работы замыкания.

Для того, чтобы уйти от глобальных переменных Вам нужна одна анонимная функция

```js
(function() {
  var printId = [];
  
  var addPrint = function(id) {
    printId.push(id);
  };
  
  var printAll = function() {
    alert(printId.length);
  };
  
  document.getElementById("print").addEventListener("click", printAll);

  var links = document.querySelectorAll(".addPrint");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    alert(links[i])
    links[i].addEventListener("click", addPrint);
    }
})();
```

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn addPrint" id="48">
  <i class="material-icons left">print</i>
  В печать
</a><br/>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn addPrint" id="49">
  <i class="material-icons left">print</i>
  В печать
</a><br/>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn addPrint" id="50">
  <i class="material-icons left">print</i>
  В печать
</a><br/>
<button id="print">Print</button>
```